# Calculate mean in Qgis filter

Tags: qgis, filter

Is there a way to calculate mean in qgis filter expression?

I tried:

```
"SHAPE_AREA" > mean("SHAPE_AREA")
```

I get:

**An error occurred when executing the query, please check the expression syntax.**

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation of  [`mean()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=mean#mean)?

Answer (score 2):

In version 3.22 this worked for me.  Open the Attribute Table, choose the Filter button and then use this formula in the field you want to filter.

```
mean("SHAPE_AREA")
```

Make sure to change the function on the right to "Greater than (>)"

[image]